# Error while forecasting with GARCH in R

Tags: r

While forecasting a time series in R, I found highly volatility hence I am using GARCH to predict.
I am seeing a unusual error while running with a single series

```
Error in solve.default(fit$hessian) : 
system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number
```

I am using Garch on the residuals I got from ARIMA using auto.arima function in R. The AR part is 1 and CH part is also 1 for the Garch. But the error is unusual to me.

Comment: The Hessian matrix should be positive definite and therefore invertible. In your case, it is not invertible and perhaps this is because it is not positive definite. If the Hessian matrix is not positive definite than the estimation method did not converge. However, the error doesn't seem to tell anything about whether the Hessian is positive definite or not so without any further code and input I can't really tell what's going on.

Comment: code used:         model_garch<-garchFit(~garch(1,1),data=data.train)